# Android UiAutomator on multiple devices, reacting to one another

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-uiautomator

Anyone got the Android uiautomator to run with multiple devices, at the same time, but doing different things?

I mean, I'd like my test to start up both devices and apps and then device A does something that device B has to react to. It seems this cannot be done with the current UiAutomatorTestRunner (which is hidden). Am I wrong?

Is my best bet to build my own TestRunner that can handle multiple devices? Tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible as the `UiAutomatorTestCase` subclass actually runs on the device. Writing a custom test runner will not resolve this problem.

I had a similar need and created a small proof of concept - [UiMutilator](https://github.com/vidstige/UiMutilator/releases)

It utlizes a a workaround - It creates several small dummy-test-methods that always pass that does the automation you need, e.g. pressing a button. The corresponding method in UiMutilator, e.g. `pressHome()` then invokes this dummy-test-methods. This way it can control multiple devices!